# Delete and Insert vs Update rows on table

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a web form in when the user can select many available items (idFamilia) for a single Provider (idProveedor) that looks like this

[image: following item]

The values are saved in this table

```
-----------------------------
| idProveedor | idFamilia   | 
-----------------------------
|      5      |      1      |
-----------------------------
|      5      |      2      |
-----------------------------
|      6      |      2      |
-----------------------------
```

After a Provider is created, it can be edited and the values selected for idFamilia can be changed. So I have three different scenarios of what could happen:

- The numbers of rows remain the same and I would only need to edit the values of idFamilia.
- Some items were deleted from the selection and I would need to search the values on the table and delete those rows.
- New items are added and I would need to insert those additional values.

Right now I am thinking about just deleting all the rows with the idProveedor that is being edited and just insert the new selection.

Is this a good practice? Will this affect the performance on the long run?

Could you recommend a tutorial or example to do it the other way?

Comment: An update will only update specified fields using less processing, versus delete/insert is more processing and more room for error if you plan on doing checks and such for security/error prevention. You also need to think down the road if the ID's of the row you'd be removing/inserting have anything dependent on that id

Comment: You gain absolutely no benefit performance-wise for doing a delete and then an insert. Why?  Because whether you do a delete or an update, the system must find the row.  Why have the system do so much more work for no appreciable benefit?

Comment: Well, the IDs for this table don't have anything dependen on them. I think I will end up doing the delete-insert, I'm trying to find a tutorial or example to do it the other way.

Comment: I'd probably use Ajax to add or remove entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always go the way to delete and re-create them.

While this adds some performance penalty, it keeps the code simple to understand and easy to maintain. Unless you're Uber, Google, Facebook, Amazon, or other world scale app, the benefits you'd get from optimizing this are much smaller than the cost it incurs: in development, debugging and maintenance time.

Comment: Yes, and it is a pain in the ass if you have to combine update with insert because the number of rows for a criteria is not the same before and after.